# TS/JS - async function worked not as expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

I don't know if I got stupid or what, but I have a big problem with that small method.

```
  async fetchContacts() {


    await this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/contacts')
    .subscribe(res => {
      const newContacts = [].concat(res);
      this.contacts = newContacts;
      console.log(this.contacts);
    });

    console.log(this.contacts);

  }
```

#### Expected result:

second console.log should be invoked after first, and returns the same value as first

### Current result:

second console.log is invoked before all the rest.

How to fix that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `await` only works with promises. Are you sure `this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/contacts')` returns a promise not an event stream? :)

Comment: thanks for the tip, I'll check it immediately :D

Comment: My get method on backend returns a promise. But I'm not quite sure what HttpClient.get do with that.

Comment: Is this angular `HttpClient` you are using? `subscribe` looks like it is an Observable, not a Promise.

Comment: yes, I use HttpClient, as I mentioned in recent comment. That URL returns promise, but HttpClient.get returns observable - vide `(method) HttpClient.get(url: string, options?: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    observe?: "body";
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | string[];
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: "json";
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<Object>`

Comment: so, is the problem lays in the fact that HttpClient.get returns Observable<Object>, not  a Observable<Promise<any>>? :D

Comment: No, the problem is that you can't use `Observable` of whatever with `await`. It only works with thenable objects (think `Promise<whatever>`). Observable is "bigger" than promise in a sense it could return multiple values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly use `await` with `Observable`. If you want to use `async/await` you could use `toPromise` operator

```
import { toPromise } from 'rxjs/operators';

async fetchContacts() {
  this.contacts = await this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/contacts').toPromise()

  ...
}
```